# How to set up Nginx reverse proxy to reach my localhosts from the internet?

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have some troubles to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy in order to have my vm's with private ip addresses being reachable from the internet.

I drew a diagram with my current configuration.

[image]

My dedicated server runs on Proxmox hypervisor and has only 1 public ip address. A bridge has been installed on the hypervisor to get the vm’s access to the internet through their local ip address.

I made some research and found this is possible with a Nginx reverse proxy to reach the vm's with a private ip address (who are running websites) from internet but I have some troubles to set it up properly.

My config /etc/network/interfaces on the hypervisor:

```
root@ns568745:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


    # vmbr0: Bridging. Make sure to use only MAC adresses that were assigned to you.
    auto vmbr0
    iface vmbr0 inet static
            address 40.53.XX.XX/24
            gateway 40.53.XX.254
            bridge_ports eno1
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_fd 0





    auto vmbr1
    iface vmbr1 inet static
            address  192.168.4.254/24
            broadcast 192.168.4.255
            bridge_ports none
            bridge_stp off
            bridge_fd 0
            post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
            post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.4.254/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
            post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.4.254/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE


    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.2:80
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.2:80
    post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.2:443
    post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.4.2:443
```

Vm1 has the ip address 192.168.4.4 and run a website (with Apache ) that has the domain name "london.austria.com"

Vm2 has the ip address 192.168.4.5 and run a website (with Apache ) that has the domain name "manchester.austria.com"

I purchased a domain name ,let’s call it, “austria.com”.

In my registrar, I set up the A records for 2 subdomains :

london.austria.com with an A record pointing to 40.53.XX.XX

manchester.austria.com with an A record pointing to 40.53.XX.XX

VM1 config: 192.168.4.4 with subdomain "london.austria.com" running wwebiste with Apache.The firewall is disabled

VM2 config: 192.168.4.5 with subdomain "manchester.austria.com" running wwebiste with Apache.The firewall is disabled

Nginx has been installed in a LXC ubuntu container with the following steps:

systemctl start nginx

systemctl enable nginx

unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

cd /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
vim reverse-proxy.conf

    server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

            location / {
                        proxy_pass http://192.168.4.4:80;
      }
    }
```

ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf

Tests I performed:

Inside the vm1:

I have access to the website by entering the ip address 192.168.4.4

I don't have access to the website by entering the domain name "london.austia.com" in a browser.

From home:

I can't access to the websites in the vm's.

I didn't even go further to test the vm2.

---

My new /etc/network/interfaces

```
root@ns568745:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback


    # vmbr0: Bridging. Make sure to use only MAC adresses that were assigned to you.
    auto vmbr0
    iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 40.53.XX.XX /24
        gateway 40.53.XX.XX .254
        bridge_ports eno1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0





    auto vmbr1
    iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  192.168.4.254/24
        broadcast 192.168.4.255
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.4.254/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.4.254/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE



    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 40.53.XX.XX  -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,22 -m comment --comment "nginx" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 40.53.XX.XX
```

Edit 1 :

So,what I did:

In a shell, I entered:

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 40.53.XX.XX -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,22 -m comment --comment "nginx" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 40.53.XX.XX
```

Then , from home, if I enter in a browser the url http://london.austria.com ,I have now access to this website.

But if I open another tab the url for the second website http://manchester.austria.com , the website displayed is still http://london.austria.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DNAT` rules are in the wrong direction (the packets coming from the Internet not your private network, i.e. interface `vmbr0`, need a translation of the destination address). Test them from a root shell, before you modify the `post-up` and `post-down` hooks:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 \
-m comment --comment "nginx" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2
```

However, since you have a static IP address (`40.53.XX.XX`), I would rather replace both the `MASQUERADE` and `DNAT` rules with:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 40.53.XX.XX -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 \
-m comment --comment "nginx" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 40.53.XX.XX
```

since the `SNAT` target is faster (cf. [netfilter manual](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDE)). This set of rules will also provide a [hairpin NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) configuration and allow you to connect from a VM to another using the server's public IP.

**Edit**: Since your network is working now, you can configure **nginx** with two `server` blocks:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    listen [::]:80 default;
    server_name manchester.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.4.5:80;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name london.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.4.4:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I modified the /etc/network/interfaces but my vm 192.168.4.4 cannot connect anymore to the internet from the hypervisor

I cannot anymore also connect to it by SSH from home ,despite I added the port 22 in --dports 80,443,22.

I edited my post with my new /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Edit: It seems it's working now. Initially,I did a ifdown vmbr1 and ifup vmbr1 but it didn't work.After rebooting the hypervisor,I have access back through ssh and the vm has access to the internet.I  have some troubles now to reach the website running on the vm1 london.austria.com from home.I will perform further tests to check if this is a problem with the apache configuration or not and update this post after.Thank you for the help!

Comment: Edit :I still cannot access the website on the vm1 london.austria.com from home.I can access it locally from the vm .I turned off the firewall and disabled selinux on the vm.

Comment: If you want to execute something, when the interface is brought up, you need to use `post-up <command>`, not just `<command>` in `/etc/network/interfaces` (and you'll want to drop the rule in `pre-down`. Leave `/etc/network/interfaces` alone, flush the **nat** table (`iptables -t nat -F`), insert the two rules from a shell. If everything is working you'll add them to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: Thank you for that information! will try later and post an update.

Comment: I sent an update in the main question.It's working half )

Comment: You need a server block per site as in the edited answer.

Comment: Update  sent in the main thread.